# Changing animation style of ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I want to change the animation style of Android's ViewPager class with using Android Animation Framework. Is it possible?

Comment: How so?  Like the speed or make it do something other than slide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my answer at: [Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android/9731345#9731345), might be helpful.

You can further customize the Scroller class to change the `Interpolator` to something more extreme.

Comment: I'm extending my pager class with pageAdapter coz i dont have fragment. I want to apply annimation on it.. How can i do it.
i tried the code   ViewPager.setObjectForPosition("--Pass fragment--", position);
 but here we have to pass fragment..

Comment: I'm extending FragmentPagerAdapter please help me your code seems to not work. the sInterpolator is d mainproblem.thanks

Comment: see the comments below the answer, you'll need to add: Interpolator sInterpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();

Answer (score 4):

You can use new android-support-v4.jar to do it.
Please reference the following official web page: Customize the Animation with PageTransformer
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this post can be helpful if you are looking for a different animation. This animation did not use android's native pager. There are some issues that should be solved but at all i think it is helpful

https://github.com/kgnkbyl/CustomViewPager

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example here

http://code.google.com/p/maniana/source/browse/#git%2FManiana%2Fsrc%2Fandroid%2Fsupport%2Fv4%2Fview

Search ViewPager.java for mForcedScrollDurationMillis. It's a hack to control the smooth scroll speed.

It also require to remove ViewPager and its internal classes from the original jar

http://code.google.com/p/maniana/source/browse/#git%2FManiana%2Flib

Something other than slide may be more involved.