# Smooth scroll does not work in ViewPager (support library)

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

I am writing application that uses `ViewPager` to host `Fragment`s.

When I change fragment programmatically the smooth scroll function does not work. I use ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)` method.

Maybe anyone know a workaround this bug? Maybe with animations?

EDIT:
I am using support package. And the issue is that whether I use `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true)` or `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false)` the result is the same. The view switches really fast (not smoothly).

Comment: First of all, the viewpager ONLY exist on the support package. Now the question would be, what is the problem you are facing ? if you do setCurrentItem(2, false) what it does instead ? can you edit your question to be a little more specific ?

Comment: So I put mPager.setCurrentItem(1, true); in a postrunnable to give a hint to the user that the object is a viewpager.  The problem is that there is no animation when I put it in the postrunnable which kills the point.  Is there another way I could do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've fixed this by creating a MyViewPager that overrides the ViewPager.mScroller using reflection.

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager 
{
  public MyViewPager( Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
  {
    super( context, attrs );
    setMyScroller();
  }
  private void setMyScroller() 
  {
    try 
    {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public class MyScroller extends Scroller 
  {
    public MyScroller(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) 
    {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 1000 /*1 secs*/);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is a nasty one, but should actually work! Thanks, I'll try to implement your suggestion.

Comment: If you use this workaround and ProGuard, you need to add this to your ProGuard config:

`-keepclassmembers class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {
 private android.widget.Scroller mScroller;
}`

Comment: I see the decelerate interpolator having an effect, but the 1 second delay in startScroll does not seem to do anything on my side.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was to call mPager.setCurrentItem after the mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), and not as a posted runnable.

Here is an example (in MonoDroid):

```
    public void UpdateDetialsView(string type)
    {
        string typeName4 = Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ParcelRecordComplaintDetailsView)).Name;

        if (_fragments.Count > 3)
        {
            _fragments.RemoveAt(_fragments.Count - 1);

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Called here it wasn't working for me (Posted or not)

            //_viewPager.Post(new Action(() => { _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(3, true); }));
        }

        _fragments.Add(Fragment.Instantiate(Activity, typeName4));

        _pagerAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Called here it works as expected

        _viewPager.SetCurrentItem(3, true);
    }
```

where

```
    protected MyAdapter _pagerAdapter;
    protected ViewPager _viewPager;
    private List<Android.App.Fragment> _fragments;
```

and

```
    public class MyAdapter : Android.Support.V13.App.FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        private List<Fragment> _fragments;

        public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(View p0, int p1)
        {
            return base.InstantiateItem(p0, p1);
        }

        public MyAdapter(Android.App.FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {

        }

        public MyAdapter(Android.App.FragmentManager fm, List<Android.App.Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
        {
            _fragments = fragments;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            //get { return FRAG_PAGES; }
            get { return _fragments.Count; }
        }

        public override Android.App.Fragment GetItem(int p0)
        {
            return _fragments[p0];
        }

        public override float GetPageWidth(int p0)
        {
            //return base.GetPageWidth(p0);

            return (float) (0.5f);
        }

        public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object p0)
        {
            //return base.GetItemPosition(p0);
            return PagerAdapter.PositionNone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. You are changing the fragments, is that correct? I don't change fragments themselves just trying to switch between them. I'll try something with this NotifyDataSetChanged() idea. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm changing them dynamically. I have 4 half screen panels that are implemented as fragments and hosted inside a ViewPager. Each panel shows the details of an item from the panel to its left (and is why I'm dynamically updating them). I don't think NotifyDataSetChanged should hurt anything if you call it without having actually changed anything beforehand, though I'm not sure if it will help (if it doesn't , maybe you can change something in a fragment very minor, change it back, then call NotifyDataSetChanged, to force it ?).