# How can i create a Horizontal List View with swipe to refresh on Android?

Tags: android, listview, swipe, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a horizontal `ListView` in Android that I can get the overscroll and do a refresh like what we do on twitter app to refresh timeline but in horizontal. My `ListView` must have image and texts

Anyone can Help me ?
[image: Side bar and 4 controls]

Comment: Usability, standard expected behavior, UI design good practices? No, never heard of it

Comment: Its a requirement in this App im doing ... no option

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like the photos gallery on Google Play, you have to use a `ViewPager` and create your own `Scroller` to extends the ViewPager's one.

I suggest to try this solution : [Smooth scroll does not work in ViewPager (support library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009180/smooth-scroll-does-not-work-in-viewpager-support-library)