# Increase viewpager smoothscroll duration

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I'm using a `ViewPager` subclass `MyPager` (which is almost the same), and I use its `setCurrentItem(int index, boolean smooth)` method, with the smooth parameter set to true. It's actually a little smoother than with parameter set to 'false', but I'd like to increase the animation duration to make the transition more visible.

I have gathered some information from different posts and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812009/change-viewpager-animation-duration-when-sliding-programmatically/14179739#comment19704416_14179739) looks perfect. I've ended up with this code"

MyPager.java :

```
public class MyPager extends ViewPager {
    public MyPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
        postInitViewPager();
    }

    private ScrollerCustomDuration mScroller = null;

    /**
     * Override the Scroller instance with our own class so we can change the
     * duration
     */
    private void postInitViewPager() {
        try {
             Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
                Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
                scroller.setAccessible(true);
                Field interpolator = viewpager.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
                interpolator.setAccessible(true);

                mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(),
                        (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null));
                scroller.set(this, mScroller);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyPager", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the factor by which the duration will change
     */
    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        mScroller.setScrollDurationFactor(scrollFactor);
    }
}
```

ScrollerCustomDuration.java

```
public class ScrollerCustomDuration extends Scroller {
    private double mScrollFactor = 2;

    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
        super(context, interpolator);
    }

    public ScrollerCustomDuration(Context context,
        Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
        super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
    }

    /**
     * Set the factor by which the duration will change
     */
    public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
        mScrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy,
            int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy,
                (int) (duration * mScrollFactor));
    }

}
```

The thing is, I can't get rid of this exception, when running through the line `scroller.set(this, mScroller);` of MyPager :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid value for field
```

Any idea?

Comment: mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(),
                        (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null)); Why did you put interpolator.get(null) ?

Comment: well, actually I didn't, but that's in the post I'm refering to... what do you suggest ?

Comment: btw, I have the same exception when I replace with " mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(),
                     new DecelerateInterpolator());"

Comment: Could you edit and post the `import` statements in your code?

Comment: NVM, just see my answer; also you use `interpolator.get(null)` because `interpolator` is static and doesn't belong to an instance.

Comment: try this, its simpler and worked for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14776244/2054956

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you modify this part of the code and insert a Log statement?

```
private void postInitViewPager() {
    try {
         Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            Field interpolator = viewpager.getDeclaredField("sInterpolator");
            interpolator.setAccessible(true);

            mScroller = new ScrollerCustomDuration(getContext(),
                    (Interpolator) interpolator.get(null));
            Log.d("TAG", "mScroller is: " + mScroller + ", "
                + mScroller.getClass().getSuperclass().getCanonicalName() + "; this class is "
                + this + ", " + getClass().getSuperclass().getCanonicalName());
            scroller.set(this, mScroller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MyPager", e.getMessage());
    }
```

And then post the output?

**EDIT**: The issue is the import statements are not correct. `mScroller` is a `android.widget.Scroller` and you cannot assign to it a `com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.widget.Scroller`.

Comment: here it is : mScroller is: com.myproject.components.ScrollerCustomDuration@416ce8f8, com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.widget.Scroller; this class is com.myproject.components.MyPager@416c7550, android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Comment: Ah, this is the problem. You are importing the wrong `Scroller`. Make sure you have `import android.widget.Scroller;`. Not `com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.widget.Scroller`.

Comment: it works, thanks so much ! I let you edit your answer or post a new one so I can validate it =)

Comment: Np, glad you got it working! Auto import isn't always right :)

Comment: If you are using proguard don't forget to add this line: -keep class android.support.v4.** {*;} otherwise you'll get null pointer when getDeclaredField()