# How to Scroll ViewPager?

Tags: android-viewpager

I am new to Android.How to use `ViewPager.scrollBy(int x,int y)`? `ViewPager.scrollBy(int x,int y)` is not updating View

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        mainPager.scrollBy(10,0);

                    }
                });
```

even this is not updating View.
please tell me what is the difference between scrollTo(int x,int y) and scrollBy(int x,int y);

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand `scrollTo()` and `scrollBy()` are not applicable to `ViewPager`; they're just methods defined by `View` that do not apply to `ViewPager`.

If you're trying to move to a specific page, use `setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)`.

Comment: Yes, but it's a bit of a hack. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14179739/832776