# How to reduce the sliding transition speed of view pager in android?

Tags: android

I need to slow down the speed of sliding in view pager when clicking the button not swiping. Since it is very high speed in default. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cehck this: 
http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1755901/
and this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812009/change-viewpager-animation-duration-when-sliding-programmatically

Comment: thankz for the reply. I just have got it from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android/9731345#9731345