# Change ViewPager min fling distance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-viewpager

I need to "slow down" ViewPager, and I want increase MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_FLING.

How can I do that?

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change ViewPager speed you can use java reflection API. Check out this topic:
[Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android)