# ViewPager swipe speed controllable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am swiping between views (not fragments), and yes each view has quite a bit of stuff happening in lists, but I would like th switch to occur quickly. It sometimes hesitates in the middle. Whatever is going on with in the pages I want to switch to occur without hesitation. I am using compatibility 4. No matter how hand I fling it hesitates in and shows both pages for a too long.  Kind of almost stops in the middle. hesitates and then shows the other page.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9731345/940096)

Comment: Use Traceview to figure out if and where you are spending too much time on the main application thread.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android)