# LinearInterpolator not working well when ViewPager Scrolls Right to Left

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-viewpager, linear-interpolation

I am using v4 ViewPager and following the below link able to 
set the scrolling speed and scrolling animation using interpolator.

[Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android/9731345#9731345)

I had used a linear interpolator when asked in the construtor like this

```
  private void setScroller() {
     try {
        Field mScroller;
        mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        mScroller.setAccessible(true); 
        FixedSpeedScroller scroller = 
           new FixedSpeedScroller(this.getContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
        mScroller.set(this, scroller);
     } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
     } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     }
  }
```

Now as i have many pages of views in my viewpages . below to it i had added pagerindicator
which consists of dots.

```
  O O O O O O O
```

Pressing a dot set the current page with smoothScrolling.
Using touch events i am able to get the right page number that i need to show.
after knowing this i call this method to have a smooth scrolling.

```
  public void snapToPage(int whichPage) {
     int numperOfSwapsRequired = whichPage - getCurrentPageIndex();
     mScrollingDuration *= numperOfSwapsRequired; 

     if(numperOfSwapsRequired == 0) return;
     if(numperOfSwapsRequired > 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i<numperOfSwapsRequired; i++){
           setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem()+1, true);
        }
     } else {
        for(int i = 0; i>numperOfSwapsRequired; i--){
           setCurrentItem(getCurrentItem()-1, true);  
        }
     }
     mScrollingDuration = 300;
  }
```

Now everything works well. But only when i select a dot which is right to the selected page dot. It properly scroll with linear animation.

But when i select dot which is left to the selected page dot. It Don't scroll. It just directly jump to the page with no scrolling animation.

So i am confused how to fix this. Is this related to interpolater or scroller.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: description of questions is too much to read.. could distract away good answers. I know that :)

Comment: try setting 'new AccelerateInterpolator()' and see if the issue still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahhhhh... It always comes to be a silly but small mistake in the end.
But thank fully i caught it. I had even started reading the Scroller Google Code file :)

```
mScrollingDuration *= numperOfSwapsRequired;
```

this number is negative when we scroll right to left causing animation time to zero.

This solved it

```
mScrollingDuration *= Math.abs(numperOfSwapsRequired);
```