# Fast scrolling does not work properly with fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android-listview

I m facing problem of fast scrolling in ViewPager from so many days.when i scroll fragments in Viewpager it does not smoothly work.I want scrolling very smoothly.Please guide me properly.!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and alter the scroller's speed.

You cannot access it directly, but you can do that by reflection and change the duration.

More detailed instructions are here:
[Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android)