# Automatic view pager in android

Tags: android

I have a problem with viewPager. I want to swipe pages automaticcly. I use handler to do that.

```
private Handler h = new Handler();
    private Runnable animateViewPager = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (!pagerMoved) {
                if (ticker == 3) {
                    h.removeCallbacks(animateViewPager);
                    h.postDelayed(startLogin, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);

                }else{
                    h.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
                }

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(ticker % adapter.getCount(), true);


                ticker++;
            }
        }

    };
```

but when I change page this is too fast. I don't see animation like when you swipe by finger. I want to use fakeDrag to simulate swipe by I don't have idea how can I do that to take 2 seconds for example. Any ideas how can I simulate smooth slide page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swipe pages automaticcly with slideshow using fade-in/out [**animation**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/anim_screenslide.webm) to switch between views

Ex: [**Using ViewPager for Screen Slides**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

for slowing down the swipe speed you need make custom [ViewPager/Scroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android).