# How can I make my view pager more smooth?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-camera

I am using a view pager to show two fragments. One fragment contains a camera preview and the other one just a simple list view.

The problem is, that the whole swipe experience is not as smooth as it should be. And I guess the reason for that is because the UI Thread has to handle the view pager, the camera and the list view all at once.

Now, what can I do about that? What can I run in a background thread? Can I run the view pager in the background?

Comment: "And I guess the reason for that is because the UI Thread has to handle the view pager, the camera and the list view all at once" -- rather than guessing, use Traceview and determine where your problem lies. BTW, I assume that you are using a `TextureView` for your camera preview.

Comment: no, i am using surface view

Comment: I will be *very* surprised if `SurfaceView` works well in a `ViewPager`, particularly a "push buffers" one, such as one for camera preview.

Comment: why? It works decent but as you said not too good

Comment: A `SurfaceView` is not a regular `View`. It is more of a hole that is punched in the window that is handed over to some low-level process, in this case the media framework for pushing preview images to the surface. A `SurfaceView` does not animate well as a result, and that may well be a contributor to your problems.

Comment: See this answer. I tried this and its perfect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android

Comment: @CommonsWare i will try to use a texture view. But how can I then support devices with api lower then 14?

Comment: @user2426316: You would have to use a `SurfaceView` for those devices, and suffer whatever consequences you may encounter.