# Revert back to default ViewPager scroller

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731345/423980) answer from a stackoveflow question about enabling a custom Scroller for ViewPager's  slide animation and it works smoothly. It extends Scroller's class and uses reflection to access the `mScroller` field.

What I want now is when some conditions have been met ( onTouch() and a timer ) to revert back to the default scroll animation.

Tried to clone the `mScroller` field :

```
        Interpolator decelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    try {
        mScroller = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        cloneDefaultScroller = mScroller;
        mScroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller = new CarouselScroller(pager.getContext(), decelerator);
        mScroller.set(pager, scroller);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    }
```

enable it again like this

```
            cloneDefaultScroller.setAccessible(true);
            Scroller scroller1 = new Scroller(this);
            cloneDefaultScroller.set(pager, scroller1)
```

where  `cloneDefaultScroller` and `mScroller` are :

```
  Field mScroller;
  Field cloneDefaultScroller;
```

but what I get is a scroller that only moves a few pixels and I have to try like 10 times to have a "normal" scroll ( from one page to another ).

Anyone can help with that? Thank you

Comment: Updated the question with some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to rename `mScroller` to `mScrollerField`, for your sanity ... why? because it is just a field description from ViewPager class, not object behind the field. Now it is obvious that there is no need for `cloneDefaultScroller` (you don't need another field description from ViewPager class but rather the field value from the instance of ViewPager)

so code should looks like(get old and set new one):

```
Field mScrollerField;
Scroller mOldScroller;

Interpolator decelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
try {
        mScrollerField= ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        mScrollerField.setAccessible(true);
        mOldScroller = (Scroller)mScrollerField.get(pager); //getting old value
        scroller = new CarouselScroller(pager.getContext(), decelerator);
        mScrollerField.set(pager, scroller);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        /*IMPORTANT at least pass the exception to logcat also for your 
        sanity (fx: in next version of compat library the field could be renamed 
        to mTheScroller and you could get NPE in restore code and then ask 
        stupid(without logcat) questions on SO why ...*/
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and restore:

```
mScrollerField.set(pager, mOldScroller);
```