# Change ViewPager scroll speed as per the scrolling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager which I need to animate when scrolled.

```
Suppose the user starts swiping\scrolling the view pager:
->the child element should start moving with FAST VELOCITY.

And when the swipe/scroll is approaching the end:
->the child element should move SLOWLY.
```

How can I do this? I tried several methods as mentioned [HERE](https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4), [HERE](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android). But none of them is giving the expected result.