# Android - NumberPicker scroll / fling faster

Tags: android, android-scroll, android-number-picker

How can I make number picker scroll/fling faster? Currently it takes so much effort from going 00 minute to 59 minute. I've tried some example from [Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android/) and applied opposite of it to number picker, but I don't see any difference.

[image]

```
try {
        Field mScroller;
        mScroller = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mFlingScroller");
        mScroller.setAccessible(true);
        FixedSpeedScroller scroller = new FixedSpeedScroller(getContext(),null,true);

        // scroller.setFixedDuration(5000);
        // scrollBy(0,1500);

        Log.v("Scroller",""+mScroller); //getting the mFlingScroller field
        mScroller.set(this, scroller);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public class FixedSpeedScroller extends Scroller {

    private int mDuration = 10;

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator) {
        super(context, interpolator);
    }

    public FixedSpeedScroller(Context context, Interpolator interpolator, boolean flywheel) {
        super(context, interpolator, flywheel);
    }


    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy) {
        // Ignore received duration, use fixed one instead
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, mDuration);
    }
}
```

I decreased the mDuration to something lower than example(5000). But still having no hope. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!!! :)

Comment: btw, I ended up using this library https://github.com/Carbs0126/NumberPickerView

Comment: in this lib no edit text available

Comment: @RajeshNasit - well the entire point is that you are picking a number/string here.

Comment: You right but I want tap to edit as well