# Android ViewPager "slide lag"

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a `ViewPager` `Fragment` with 3 fragments. Each of it has an image as background and a `TextView`. The `TextView` is always absolute on the left side of the screen (not the `Fragment` itself). When I move the fragments with my finger, it stays at the correct position. Also when I move it fast. But when I let it slide into the other `Fragment`, the `TextView` doesn't stays at the correct position. It looks like it lags around.

**It should stay like in these 2 pictures:**

[image]
[image]

```
 @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        SingleTabFragment singleTabFragment = (SingleTabFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(position);
        TextView textView = singleTabFragment.getNonResizingTextView();
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
        marginLayoutParams.leftMargin = positionOffsetPixels;
        textView.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);

    }
```

I really don't know what the problem is. I tried it multiple ways, i added `Thread.sleep(50);` to see if it also happens there. And yes, also there it doesn't work correct. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

Now I have put in the middle. But the problem is the same.

Here is how it should look like (I know, not that much frames. But I think you will get the point):
[image]

And if I let it slide it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a gif with that behavior?

Comment: @azizbekian yes, I've edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TextView textView = singleTabFragment.getNonResizingTextView();
 textView.translationX = positionOffsetPixels;
```

You should not do `marginLayoutParams.leftMargin = positionOffsetPixels;` because changing the margin may change the position of the View, which will cause the View to be re-layout on every frame. That is why it is lagging. 
Changing the `translationX` will only change `how the view is drawn` instead of it's position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method to do the same instead of doing it in onPageScrolled:

```
mPager.setPageTransformer(false, new FadePageTransformer());

public class FadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            view.setAlpha(1 - Math.abs(position));
                    if (position < 0) {
                        view.setScrollX(-(int) ((float) (view.getWidth()) * -position));
                    } else if (position > 0) {
                        view.setScrollX((int) ((float) (view.getWidth()) * position));
                    } else {
                        view.setScrollX(0);
                    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `textView.setTranslationX(positionOffsetPixels);` instead of margins

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android)

You can set custom duration for Viewpager scrolling.