# Viewpager TabLayout Tab change when swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, android-tablayout

I want to change tab when user 20% of view swipe but right now if i swipe around 60 present then tab change. other wise it back previous tab. how can i do that.

```
   viewPager = (ViewPagerCustomDuration) findViewById(R.id.tabs_viewpager);
        viewPager.setScrollDurationFactor(1);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        viewPager.animate().translationX(0f).setDuration(500);
        final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        viewPager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);
        // viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabFragmentPagerAdapter = new TabFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this, viewPager);
        tabFragmentPagerAdapter.addFrag(new HomeFragment(), "Home");
        tabFragmentPagerAdapter.addFrag(new DiscoverFragment(), "Discover");
        tabFragmentPagerAdapter.addFrag(new TopFragment(), "Top");
        tabFragmentPagerAdapter.addFrag(new CategoryFragment(), "Category");


        // setupViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

[image]

Comment: share your code.

Comment: add my code please chcek

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14209409/4549220 use this for ViewPagerCustomDuration