# Control View Pager Slides with Timer Task

Tags: android, android-viewpager, timertask

I'm trying to slide my ViewPager automatically via using TimerTask class, seems I do not have proper delay and period, it is sliding so fast. I tried all possible combinations of delay and period parameters without any luck, still so annoying fast sliding. Below is the code:

```
class SliderTimer extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HomeActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < listSlides.size() - 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the implementations:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new HomeActivity.SliderTimer(), 10000, 10000);
```

Please guide me, what best can be done for the same.

Comment: how fast you need it

Comment: I have 30 items so, 1 seconds delay for each would be appreciated.

Comment: What if user start slide manually ? This will become a mess . To avoid this Use `Handler` in `OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: How will be that?

Comment: You can refer to available library https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager. It helps you

Comment: `10000` is 10 seconds right? Then how can you say that it's fast

Comment: It is not working anyway, I know that is 10 seconds but it is not obeying that parameter.

Comment: @RahulSingh Check my answer..it might help you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Using `Handler` is better then `TimerTask` in this case if `ViewPager` can slide manually too.
First Create a `Handler` and `Runnable` Globally.

```
private Handler handler=new Handler();
private Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(pagerSlider.getCurrentItem()==data.size()-1){
            pagerSlider.setCurrentItem(0,false);
        }else{
            pagerSlider.setCurrentItem(pagerSlider.getCurrentItem()+1);
        }
    }
};
```

Post the runnable inside `onPageChange`.

```
 pagerSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable,2000);
        }
    });
```

You need to post for first time Rest the listener will do. Change the delay as per your need :-

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable,2000);
```

I just realize that you might be asking about scrolling velocity . Well for this you need to use Customize Scroller. [Go to This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android).

Comment: Do I need to override the onPageChange method?

Comment: Yeah as its above in answer.  I think you are asking about scrolling velocity . For this i have attached a link above. If this question is specific to scrolling velocity then and you found solution in the link above then pls mark it as duplicate ..

Comment: bro will you please explain how to use that custom scroll class, seems a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Its all there in the link above .. i don't its need any more explanation.

Comment: What goes in interpolator?

Comment: I implemented but it is not scrolling anyway.

Comment: just use `new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()` in place of interpolator.

Comment: Yes, now it is working, but this is not what I wanted, I wanted to scroll it automatically.

Comment: to scroll it automatically you need to use the code i have provided above..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you saved my day, one more problem I can not see or implement the opPageChange method, there is no such method available.

Comment: Voila! I figured it out, again thanks a ton pal, you were so helpful, god bless you mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
public static final long DELAY_MS = 2000;
public static final long PERIOD_MS = 4000;

new MyTimerHeader(DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS, viewPager, images_total_length);

public MyTimerHeader(long DELAY_MS, long PERIOD_MS, final ViewPager slider1, final 
int image_name) {
    final int image_name1=image_name;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            int currentPage = slider1.getCurrentItem();

            if (currentPage == image_name1 - 1) {
                currentPage = 0;
            }
            else {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
            }
            slider1.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
        }



    };

    Timer timer = new Timer(); // This will create a new Thread
    timer .schedule(new TimerTask() { // task to be scheduled

        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.post(Update);

        }
    }, DELAY_MS, PERIOD_MS);
}
```