# How can i change default speed of viewpager auto sliding in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I use below code to change default speed of sliding in viewpager.
I try java code, [This Stackoverflow question's Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android).
I use below kotlin code to set limit of animation of auto swipe of view pager

```
val mScroller = ViewPager::class.java.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
mScroller.setAccessible(true);
val scroller = Scroller(requireContext(), DecelerateInterpolator());
mScroller.set(mPager, scroller);
```

But non of code working for kotlin, and give this crash

```
05-08 19:21:59.690 23859-23859/com.mindfulness.greece A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 23859 (dfulness.greece)
05-08 19:21:59.820 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-08 19:21:59.820 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:6.0/MASTER/5056751:userdebug/test-keys'
05-08 19:21:59.820 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
05-08 19:21:59.820 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
05-08 19:21:59.821 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: pid: 23859, tid: 23859, name: dfulness.greece  >>> com.mindfulness.greece <<<
05-08 19:21:59.821 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
05-08 19:21:59.830 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx b5ba0398  ecx 00000002  edx 00000000
05-08 19:21:59.831 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     esi 9b6bd6bc  edi 00000028
05-08 19:21:59.831 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000007b
05-08 19:21:59.831 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     eip b5b111d0  ebp bf742000  esp bffa6030  flags 00210286
05-08 19:21:59.832 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-08 19:21:59.832 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0002a1d0  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 19:21:59.832 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0003e9eb  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DisplayListCanvas::drawCircle(float, float, float, SkPaint const&)+251)
05-08 19:21:59.832 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000d581c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
05-08 19:21:59.833 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 737055f0  /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb2000)
05-08 19:21:59.833 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00002ca3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (offset 0xb3000)
05-08 19:21:59.833 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0003a193  /system/lib/libhwui.so (non-virtual thunk to android::uirenderer::DisplayListCanvas::~DisplayListCanvas()+9)
05-08 19:21:59.833 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0003a20f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
05-08 19:21:59.833 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 027010eb  [heap]
05-08 19:21:59.980 7677-7677/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_05
05-08 19:21:59.981 7677-7677/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
05-08 19:22:00.100 1640-1696/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'eb88da6 com.mindfulness.greece/com.mindfulness.greece.activity.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-08 19:22:00.191 1640-6583/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
05-08 19:22:00.192 1640-6583/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
05-08 19:22:00.192 1640-6583/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
05-08 19:22:00.259 1955-2211/com.android.launcher3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
05-08 19:22:00.259 1955-2211/com.android.launcher3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
05-08 19:22:00.260 1955-2211/com.android.launcher3 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it, I think it will help you...

```
private fun init() {


    mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager) as ViewPager
    mPager!!.adapter = SlidingImage_Adapter(this@MainActivity, this.imageModelArrayList!!)

    val indicator = findViewById(R.id.indicator) as CirclePageIndicator

    indicator.setViewPager(mPager)

    val density = resources.displayMetrics.density

    //Set circle indicator radius
    indicator.setRadius(5 * density)

    NUM_PAGES = imageModelArrayList!!.size

    // Auto start of viewpager
    val handler = Handler()
    val Update = Runnable {
        if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
            currentPage = 0
        }
        mPager!!.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true)
    }
    val swipeTimer = Timer()
    swipeTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            handler.post(Update)
        }
    }, 3000, 3000)

    // Pager listener over indicator
    indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            currentPage = position

        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(pos: Int, arg1: Float, arg2: Int) {

        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(pos: Int) {

        }
    })

}

companion object {

    private var mPager: ViewPager? = null
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var NUM_PAGES = 0
}
```