# Change ViewPager2 Scroll Speed when sliding programmatically

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

I know there is way to change animation duration of `ViewPager` programmatical slide ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731345/4565796)).

But its not working on `ViewPager2`

I tried this:

```
try {
        final Field scrollerField = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scrollerField.setAccessible(true);
        final ResizeViewPagerScroller scroller = new ResizeViewPagerScroller(getContext());
        scrollerField.set(mViewPager, scroller);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

IDE gives me warning on "mScroller":

> Cannot resolve field 'mScroller'

If we Run This code thats not going to work and give us Error below:

```
No field mScroller in class Landroidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2; (declaration of 'androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2' appears in /data/app/{packagename}-RWJhF9Gydojax8zFyFwFXg==/base.apk)
```

So how we can acheive this functionality?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Based on [this issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122656759) Android team is not planning to support such behavior for ViewPager2, advise from the ticket is to use `ViewPager2.fakeDragBy()`. Disadvantage of this method is that you have to supply page width in pixels, although if your page width is the same as ViewPager's width then you can use that value instead.

Here's sample implementation

```
fun ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(
    item: Int,
    duration: Long,
    interpolator: TimeInterpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator(),
    pagePxWidth: Int = width // Default value taken from getWidth() from ViewPager2 view
) {
    val pxToDrag: Int = pagePxWidth * (item - currentItem)
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, pxToDrag)
    var previousValue = 0
    animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        val currentValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val currentPxToDrag = (currentValue - previousValue).toFloat()
        fakeDragBy(-currentPxToDrag)
        previousValue = currentValue
    }
    animator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) { beginFakeDrag() }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) { endFakeDrag() }
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
    })
    animator.interpolator = interpolator
    animator.duration = duration
    animator.start()
}
```

---

To support `RTL` you have to flip the value supplied to `ViewPager2.fakeDragBy()`, so from above example instead of `fakeDragBy(-currentPxToDrag)` use `fakeDragBy(currentPxToDrag)` when using `RTL`.

Few things to keep in mind when using this, based on [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#fakedragby):

- negative values scroll forward, positive backward (flipped with RTL)
- before calling `fakeDragBy()` use `beginFakeDrag()` and after you're finished `endFakeDrag()`
- this API can be easily used with `onPageScrollStateChanged` from `ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback`, where you can distinguish between programmatical drag and user drag thanks to `isFakeDragging()` method
- sample implementation from above doesn't have security checks if the given item is correct. Also consider adding cancellation capabilities for UI's lifecycle, it can be easily achieved with RxJava.

Comment: This example worked on my project, but , for some reason the items between the first and last one have some giggle effect when they slide, but the last item just slides into the right way, is this caused by the px of the offset?

Comment: @GastónSaillén this behavior indicates that you might have used wrong value for page width in pixels. Jiggle was from overscrolling or not scrolling far enough?

Comment: or you meant that jiggle is in the middle of the scroll?

Comment: when it finishes to slide , it jiggles before stop a little bit at the end, the jiggle is at the end of the scroll

Comment: @GastónSaillén try playing with pagePxWidth value, modify it slightly and see what happens. If by jiggle you mean scroll past the item you selected and snap back to center it'd mean that setCurrentItem method is overscrolling and viewpager is snapping back to selected item.

Comment: yes, thats the jiggle effect, if I change pagePxWidth will it adjust to all screen sizes as well ?

Comment: @MTomczyński, That makes sense. Can you share the java code that has same functionality?

Comment: @MTomczyński I'm using this code in conjunction with code that essentially "auto-scrolls" items every 1 sec, plus a viewpager that shows a portion of adjacent items. What happens is that sometimes viewpager overscrolls, ending up 1 item away from the intended item. What can you suggest I tweak?

Comment: nvm @MTomczyński I figured out the correct pagePxWidth value

Comment: @akubi Sorry! I didn't had a chance to look into it. Out of curiosity, what was the solution?

Comment: @MTomczyński no worries, I arrived at the correct pagePxWidth by subtracting the left and right padding I applied to the inner recyclerview of ViewPager2 from the actual ViewPager2 width in pixels.

Comment: I am using this in conjunction with `setPageTransformer` that adds offsets so that adjacent pages are "peeking", and it's not working so well :( Sometimes this method results in shaky animation, and sometimes it isn't enough to reach target item

Comment: you have to calculate offsets and paddings into the `pagePxWidth` value. Given implementation is only a sample one for the case where your page is the same width as the ViewPager view itself. When you'll calculate `pagePxWidth` correctly there won't be any jiggle

Comment: @MTomczyński yep I tried incorporating the correct offsets and paddings but still no success. I guess this is just a limitation of the ViewPager2 itself :(

Comment: @akubi you could try passing the width of the displayed child view instead of calculating it with padding? You could double-check the calculations that way ;)

Comment: Can that code be applicable to Java? Since ViewPager2 is final, we can't?

Comment: @chitgoks oh for sure, move the ViewPager2 receiver to argument list of the method and transform the code in the method itself to Java. Because you can't use default parameters you'll have to specify them explicitly on the method call, like for pagePxWidth

Comment: @MTomczynski how can this be applied with a ViewPager2 TabLayout combo?

Comment: I am getting this error randomly not everytime after using this approach : "Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Cannot change current item when ViewPager2 is fake dragging" .

Comment: just reiterating here that `fakeDragBy` is incredibly unstable, when I had it in my app it would always in one way or another for about 0.5% of users. I strongly advise against implementing a custom solution like this

Answer (score 6):

ViewPager2 team made it REALLY hard to change the scrolling speed. If you look at the method setCurrentItemInternal, they instantiate their own private ScrollToPosition(..) object. along with state management code, so this would be the method that you would have to somehow override.

As a solution from here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122656759, they say use `(ViewPager2).fakeDragBy()` which is super ugly.

Not the best, just have to wait form them to give us an API to set duration or copy their ViewPager2 code and directly modify their LinearLayoutImpl class.

Comment: they ice boxed the issue, this is ridiculous

Comment: agree. there should be a scrolling speed. because their current scrolling speed sucks especially when you switch from 1 tab to the next.

Answer (score 2):

When you want your ViewPager2 to scroll with your speed, and in your direction, and by your number of pages, on some button click, call this function with your parameters. Direction could be leftToRight = true if you want it to be that, or false if you want from right to left, duration is in miliseconds, numberOfPages should be 1, except when you want to go all the way back, when it should be your number of pages for that viewPager:

```
fun fakeDrag(viewPager: ViewPager2, leftToRight: Boolean, duration: Long, numberOfPages: Int) {
    val pxToDrag: Int = viewPager.width
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, pxToDrag)
    var previousValue = 0
    animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        val currentValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        var currentPxToDrag: Float = (currentValue - previousValue).toFloat() * numberOfPages
        when {
            leftToRight -> {
                currentPxToDrag *= -1
            }
        }
        viewPager.fakeDragBy(currentPxToDrag)
        previousValue = currentValue
    }
    animator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) { viewPager.beginFakeDrag() }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) { viewPager.endFakeDrag() }
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) { /* Ignored */ }
    })
    animator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    animator.duration = duration
    animator.start()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by M Tomczynski (Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59235979/7608625) is good one. But I faced app randomly crashing when used along with inbuilt setCurrentItem() because of fakeDrag even though i ensured to call endDrag() before using setCurrentItem(). So I modified the solution to use viewpager's embeded recycler view's scrollBy() function which is working very well without any issues.

```
fun ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(
    index: Int,
    duration: Long,
    interpolator: TimeInterpolator = PathInterpolator(0.8f, 0f, 0.35f, 1f),
    pageWidth: Int = width - paddingLeft - paddingRight,
) {
    val pxToDrag: Int = pageWidth * (index - currentItem)
    val animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, pxToDrag)
    var previousValue = 0

    val scrollView = (getChildAt(0) as? RecyclerView)
    animator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        val currentValue = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val currentPxToDrag = (currentValue - previousValue).toFloat()
        scrollView?.scrollBy(currentPxToDrag.toInt(), 0)
        previousValue = currentValue
    }

    animator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) { }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            // Fallback to fix minor offset inconsistency while scrolling
            setCurrentItem(index, true)
            post { requestTransform() } // To make sure custom transforms are applied
        }
        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) { /* Ignored */ }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) { /* Ignored */ }
    })

    animator.interpolator = interpolator
    animator.duration = duration
    animator.start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using ViewPager2..

Make CustomPagerSnapHelper by extending PagerSnapHelper and override the createSnapScroller function

Below is the code for the same.
note: In my case I just multiplied time 2x which result in slower animation. change the time variable according to your need. I recommend just multiple to further slower the animation instead of hardcoded value

```
public class CustomPagerSnapHelper extends PagerSnapHelper {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 100f;
    private static final int MAX_SCROLL_ON_FLING_DURATION = 100; // ms

    CustomPagerSnapHelper(RecyclerView mRecyclerView) {
        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    protected LinearSmoothScroller createSnapScroller(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        if (!(layoutManager instanceof RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new LinearSmoothScroller(mRecyclerView.getContext()) {
            @Override
            protected void onTargetFound(View targetView, RecyclerView.State state, Action action) {
                int[] snapDistances = calculateDistanceToFinalSnap(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager(),
                        targetView);
                final int dx = snapDistances[0];
                final int dy = snapDistances[1];
                final int time = calculateTimeForDeceleration(Math.max(Math.abs(dx), Math.abs(dy)));
                if (time > 0) {
                    action.update(dx, dy, time*2/* time represent the duration of scroll animation */, mDecelerateInterpolator);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
            }

            @Override
            protected int calculateTimeForScrolling(int dx) {
                return Math.min(MAX_SCROLL_ON_FLING_DURATION, super.calculateTimeForScrolling(dx));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

use reflection to replace PagerSnapHelper with our CustomPagerSnapHelper object. our object will to injected here >>>>>> ViewPager.mRecylerView.mPagerSnapHelper >> then attach recyclerview to our CustomPagerSnapHelper

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);
        
        try {
            Field mScroller = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView");
            mScroller.setAccessible(true);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mScroller.get(viewPager);

            Field pagerSnap = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mPagerSnapHelper");
            pagerSnap.setAccessible(true);
            CustomPagerSnapHelper customPagerSnapHelper = new CustomPagerSnapHelper(recyclerView);
            pagerSnap.set(viewPager,customPagerSnapHelper);
            recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
            customPagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        viewPager.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, images));
```