# Tab layout transition delay is very fast

Tags: android

Am using custom animations in view pager and these animations works perfectly when swiping left or right,but when pressing on the tabs itself without swiping, the animations is done very fast causing damage to the eye, so is there any function to change the delay when pressing on the tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing comes to my mind is making delay with a handler but delaying the transition between pages may cause unexpected result because of user behavior like clicking buttons very fast. I recommend making the view pager's transition animation a little slower. You can achieve such a behavior by using the [Slowing speed of Viewpager controller in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155257/slowing-speed-of-viewpager-controller-in-android)